# Handling org.apache.arrow.vector.util.OversizedAllocationException error

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark data frame that has two columns, probability and true label (from a binary classifier).
The data is already provided to me (so I am not performing any Mlib operations on my own). The size of the Data is ~500M,I have a cluster with 8 workers of 112 GB memory (1 GPU , 5 DBUs). I need to calculate roc_auc_score. I am using a pandas UDF along with sklearn's roc_auc_score metric.

Below is the code:

```
@pandas_udf("double")
      def pandas_auc(label: pd.Series,probability: pd.Series) -> float:
        score = roc_auc_score(y_true= label, y_score=probability)
        return score
# execute 
training_auc = self.df.select(pandas_auc('label','Average_Score')).first()[0]
```

This throws the error :

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 30.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 30.0 (TID 7923, 10.70.176.13, executor 3): org.apache.arrow.vector.util.OversizedAllocationException: Memory required for vector capacity 264305678 is (2147483648), which is more than max allowed (2147483647)
```

I noticed that it works with lesser data (~100M), but how do I handle this when my data is ~500?

Comment: function, spark uses Arrow framework for data transformation between Spark data frame and pandas data frame, not sure what version of Arrow you are using, if it is 0.14 or less then, you can convert only below 2GB of data ** UNCOMPRESSED**

Comment: try checking size of your uncompressed data by saving as CSV file.

Comment: not sure which version of spark you are using but there are few work arounds to over come this issue.  store the in S3 by partition column and make a boto3 call from your pandas UDF function and store it back to S3 (is the size of the result is smaller than 2GB the you can return that as output from your Pandas UDF) if you are using HDFS then make a webhdfs call

Comment: or try to change the datatype of your data with out any precision loss, so that overall size of the partition can be reduced

Comment: what datatype should I use ?

Comment: what are the current datatype ?

Comment: may be you can referent this and use the smaller data types if possible

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datatypes.html

Comment: I will try that... But what if I get more data in the future and I have to do the same ...and that is definitely going to happen 

Comment: we can explore more options, if you share  spark version and details on where your data is stored,   S3 or HDFS

Comment: sure, it 3.0.1 and I am using azure Databricks, so its guess DBFS